# Screen pinning fails after device restart

Tags: android

In my owner device app on Android 6.0 device, I have called `setLockTaskPackages()` and then `startLockTask()` like following:

```
...
mDPM.setLockTaskPackages("com.foo.myapp");
...
startLockTask();
```

It works on screen pinning at the installation of the app, but after device restarts and app start again, screen pinning fails by "screen unpinned" toast.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: have you got any solution?